# Why is it creating a method type object, I want an object of type list

Tags: python, pandas

```
un=df.WFID.unique
type(un)
>> method
```

`WFID` is a column with integer values and I want to get unique IDs from it.

Comment: Try: `un=df.WFID.unique()`. This returns a list of unique values

Comment: Because `df.WFID.unique` is a method, in particular, it is `pd.Series.unique`, you want to *call the method* to get the values you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unique` is a method, you need to call it

```
un = df.WFID.unique()
```